# Unique Solution Periodic Differential Equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, inverse, periodic-functions, singular-solution

I am reading in a book and I encountered this step that I do not understand in the proof. The book is proving the following:

$ \frac{dx}{dt} = A(t) x + f(t) $

where $A(t)$ is a continuous $n \times n$ matrix on $\mathbb{R}$, and $A(t + \omega) = A(t)$, $\omega > 0$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\phi(t)$ be a solution matrix with $\det \phi(t) \neq 0$. Show that if the differential equation has a unique $\omega$-periodic solution, then $\left[\phi^{-1}(\omega) - \phi^{-1}(0) \right]$ is non-singular.

In the end, they were able to show this

$ \phi(\omega) \left[ \phi^{-1}(\omega) - I \right] x_0 = \phi(\omega) \int_0^\omega \phi^{-1}(\omega) f(s) \,ds$

and then jumped to the conclusion that

$\left| \phi^{-1}(\omega) - \phi^{-1}(0) \right| \neq 0$

or else this is no unique solution. I am confused on why they can say if you want a unique solution, then $\left| \phi^{-1}(\omega) - \phi^{-1}(0) \right| \neq 0$.

Then I am also confused to about why saying $\left| \phi^{-1}(\omega) - \phi^{-1}(0) \right| \neq 0$ should make $\left[ \phi^{-1}(\omega) - \phi^{-1}(0) \right]$ non-singular.

Please show me the reasons, thank you. Let me know if you don't have enough information. I only gave the end of the proof.

Comment: They are using $| \cdot |$ to denote determinant.  A square matrix is nonsingular if and only if its determinant is nonzero.

Comment: ok. that I understand that part now. Thank you. But what about the first part? how did they get conclude from their integral that the determinant must be zero to get the unique solution?

Comment: Can I know what is the name of the book you were reading at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some of your formulas have typos.
The solution of the system with initial value $x(0)=x_0$ is
$$ x(t) = \phi(t) \left(x_0 + \int_0^t \phi(s)^{-1} f(s)\; ds\right)$$
In particular, with $t = \omega$, the solution is periodic iff $x(\omega) = x_0$, i.e.
$$ (I - \phi(\omega)) \; x_0 =  \phi(\omega) \int_{0}^{\omega} \phi(s)^{-1} f(s) ds$$
The  periodic solution is unique (i.e. there is exactly one $x_0$ that satisfies this) if and only if $I - \phi(\omega)$ is nonsingular, i.e.
$\left| I- \phi(\omega) \right| \ne 0$.
I think the authors are assuming $\phi(0)=I$, and since $I - \phi(\omega) = \phi(\omega) (\phi(\omega)^{-1} - I)$ and the determinant of a product is the product of the determinants this is
also equivalent to $\left| \phi(\omega)^{-1} - \phi(0)^{-1}\right| \ne 0$